# SQL update with inner join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm using SQL Server and I want to update 2 values (ActionNumber and NumberOfPeople) from InterventionsImage where the property NumberOfInterverntion  have same value from both ExecuteInterventions  and InterventionsImage tables.

Using the logic of SQL update sintax i tried something like this query:

```
        UPDATE ExecuteInterventions ei INNER JOIN InterventionsImage ii
        ON ei.NumberOfInterverntion = ii.NumberOfIntervention
        SET ii.ActionNumber = 1 and SET ii.NumberOfPeople = 233
        WHERE ei.ID = 153 and ii.ID  = 199687
```

should update the ActionNumber and NumberOfIntervention values from InterventionsImage table. But of course that does not worked.
Can someone figure me out how can i update those values?

Comment: duplicate:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new using Sql server i recommend to do this.

First try to select values that you want to update by using a select clause

```
Select * 
FROM ExecuteInterventions ei INNER JOIN InterventionsImage ii
ON ei.NumberOfInterverntion = ii.NumberOfIntervention
WHERE ei.ID = 153 and ii.ID  = 199687
```

Check if those values are the ones that you want to change

Then apply update clause on the following way

```
Update ii
SET ii.ActionNumber = 1
  , ii.NumberOfPeople = 233
FROM ExecuteInterventions ei INNER JOIN InterventionsImage ii
ON ei.NumberOfInterverntion = ii.NumberOfIntervention
WHERE ei.ID = 153 and ii.ID  = 199687
```

Copy FROM structure from your query and put an Update clause on it by.
On update clause invoke alias of table that you want to update (Ex ii)
and apply set clause to change info that you want.

Answer (score 0):

try below query. this should work...

UPDATE ii
SET ii.ActionNumber = 1, 
    ii.NumberOfPeople = 233
From InterventionsImage ii INNER JOIN ExecuteInterventions ei
ON ei.NumberOfInterverntion = ii.NumberOfIntervention
WHERE ei.ID = 153 and ii.ID  = 199687